# phpの再インストール

Tags: php, linux

以前サーバにインストールしたphpの環境を手違いで消してしまいました。

```
# yum remove php
```

そこで再インストールしたところ下記のエラーが出ます
環境はCentOS release 6.6 (Final)

```
# yum install php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * elrepo: ftp.ne.jp
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.bjtu.edu.cn
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.bjtu.edu.cn
108 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-47.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6 for package: php-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6 for package: php-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6
           Installed: php-common-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.41-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6
Error: Package: php-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6
           Installed: php-cli-5.4.41-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.41-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

再インストールするにはどのようにすればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

英語が読めないという質問でしょうか。
php-commonとphp-cliも再インストールするか、インストール済みのphp-common, php-cliで動作するphpをインストールしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 大変失礼しました
焦ってよく読まずに質問を上げてしまいました
おっしゃる通りphp-commonを消してから再インストールしたところうまくいきました
ありがとうございました